# Jqgrid Not Displaying All Records (Search and Number of Records To Display)

Tags: jqgrid, rownum

I am using jqSuitePHP_4_4_4_0 and stumbled on the following odd scenario.

1. Initial load of data into grid completes (a few thousand records)
2. Search for a particular value which returns all records (17) fitting the criteria BUT
3. Not all records are *displayed* (15 displayed of 17 returned)
4. Change the `rowList` select menu to anything larger than the total records returned and then all 17 appear.

My `rowNum` is 30 and my `rowList: [10, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]`.

So I'm not sure how when the initial results are returned why I see 15 records until I set the select menu to `100` or more.

Why is this happening and what should be done to correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting: this is only in production, the dev app works properly.  Checking code diffs.

Comment: More interesting - diff revealed nothing, prod and dev are the same.